# internationalization with pyramid and python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, internationalization, pyramid

What is the current state of internationalization support for Pyramid using Python 3?

Currently it seems that the packages Pyramid uses for this, lingua and babel, aren't Python 3 compatible.

There is https://bitbucket.org/felixschwarz/babel-py3k, but no official release.

Also for lingua, I could only find shadows of something called lingua3k, but the links to it everywhere were broken and also no official releases.

How can I get myself up and running with Pyramid i18n and Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find any info about the status (current or future) of i18n helper packages for pyramid in python 3 (babel and lingua).

To solve this inconvenience, I did 4 things:

1. Create a 2nd virtual environment with python2.7
2. Add a specific i18n setup file called setup_i18n.py
3. Write a simple wrapper script called translate.py which setup.py will call to do translations.
4. Add an entry point in setup.py to point to the translate script.

Details:

1. I created a very lean 2nd virtual and very lean env with python2.7 inside my project. Just called it env_python_2.7 and put it in the root of my project.
2. Then in the directory where setup.py lives I created another setup file, setup_i18n.py. This file only makes requirements for just what is needed for i18n support. My setup_i18n.py file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

requires = [
    'Babel',
    'lingua',
]

setup(name='my_project',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=requires,

      message_extractors={'.': [
          ('**.py', 'lingua_python', None),
          ('**.pt', 'lingua_xml', None),
          ]},
      )
```

1. Then I created a script called translate.py and put that in the same scripts directory that initializedb.py goes into when you create a project from a template. The script is pretty general and could be made to have more specific targets, but it looks like this

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import sys

from pyramid.paster import (
    get_appsettings,
    setup_logging,
    )

description = """\
A script to facilitate the translation of strings in the app.
"""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description)
parser.add_argument('ini_file', help='Ini file to setup environment for this script')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', metavar='locale',
                    help='Add locale name of new language for translation (eg: en, de)')

def main(argv=sys.argv):
    args = parser.parse_args()

    setup_logging(args.ini_file)
    settings = get_appsettings(args.ini_file)

    # Python 2.7 is needed for translation strings at this time, because the
    # available translation string tools are not compatible with Python 3
    # at this time
    python27 = settings['my_project.python27_dir'] + '/bin/python'
    setup_file = settings['my_project.i18n_setup_file']

    if args.add:
        subprocess.call([python27, setup_file, 'init_catalog', '-l', args.add])

    subprocess.call([python27, setup_file, 'extract_messages'])
    subprocess.call([python27, setup_file, 'update_catalog'])
    subprocess.call([python27, setup_file, 'compile_catalog'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1. And finally, I modified the setup.py entry points to point to the translate script. My entry points look like:

```
entry_points="""\
[paste.app_factory]
main = my_project:main
[console_scripts]
my_project_db = my_project.script.initializedb:main
my_project_translate = my_project.script.translate:main
""",
```

Now I can i18n my app by calling 'python3 setup.py my_project_translate'

Answer (score 5):

## Py3 Status 6/28/2013

This is an updated answer over the two answers posted in March of 2013 for anyone who happens to stumble upon this.

Work on Babel  for Python 3 has not been officially published. The maintainers have an open ticket that has not had any resolution here: http://babel.edgewall.org/ticket/209

However, a group of individuals have picked up the torch and started an unofficial BitBucket repo to house their work on Babel3: https://bitbucket.org/babel3_developers/babel3

Pyramid also uses lingua. At present if you attempt to easy_install/pip install lingua, it will fail. The sole reason for this is that xlwt hasn't been ported officially.

If you want lingua to install you will have to manually patch xlwt.

## Install Unofficial Babel3

Right now, there is no official release for Babel in Python 3. There is also nothing posted to pypi (i.e. easy_install babel/babel3 or pip install babel/babel3 don't properly work). However you can use the unofficial release.

1. To get the unofficial release, first you need to have an installation of mercurial (source control tool). You need this to check out the source code from BitBucket. You can get that here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/ for windows users. For Linux/Unix use your distro tools to get binaries or compile from source.
2. From a command prompt navigate to a directory where you want to temporarily store the Babel3 source install files; then run: hg clone https://bitbucket.org/babel3_developers/babel3 (Windows users might need to either type the full path to hg.exe or ensure they add the directory hg.exe is to their path)
3. This will create a directory on your local machine that contains a setup.py file. Move into the new directory and execute the file: python setup.py install

## Installing Lingua

Pyramid's i18n relies upon another Python module named lingua. It is having problems with another module dependency named xlwt. It has also been unofficially patched here: https://github.com/tonyroberts/xlwt

1. Obtain the source for the patched version of xlwt here: https://github.com/tonyroberts/xlwt (click Download zip on the bottom right)
2. Extract contents to temp location
3. Navigate a command prompt inside the resulting directory
4. Run: python setup.py install
5. Now install lingua via: pip install lingua -or- easy_install lingua

Comment: When I try to extract messages, I get an error message: "ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'".  Which is Python 2 usage from Lingua, I think.  So maybe need to get the latest source of Lingua too?

Comment: There is a commit for Python 3 support on the Flask-Babel Github, but I haven't tested it: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/commit/157fe4d49d7a7c7cb9e170e2bceebee2e49f11a2

Answer (score 1):

To translate a Python app in your way, you generally have two distinct steps:

- Extracting the message catalog
- Translating the strings

The first part is handled by Babel and lingua, the second part is gettext (or any wrapper around it, e.g. [translationstring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/translationstring).

**Short answer**: Download Poedit for the catalog work and use the regular Pyramid library for the translation.

### Long answer

So if Babel and lingua won't work for you, you could create your message catalog yourself. Then, with an existing `.pot` file, you can create your `.po` files for every language. If you use [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) it can automatically compile your `.po` files into `.mo` files. These in turn can be handled without any dependency just using Python's standard library [gettext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html#module-gettext).

So here is what you do: Use Poedit to create a message catalog (`File->New Catalog`). Apply all settings carefully. Poedit can even extract strings, maybe you do not need manual work here, just take a look at *Sources paths* and *Sources keywords* in the *Catalog properties*.

Then you translate all your (extracted or manually added) strings. Pyramid will expect the following directory structure

```
myproject/
    locale/
        en/
            LC_MESSAGES/
                myproject.po
                myproject.mo
        myproject.pot
```

The `pot` file is your catalog. The `en` folder is for translation to english. For any other language put in the locale here: `de` for German, `es` for Spanish, etc. You may create the `.po` file empty and let Poedit update from the `.pot` file.

When you are done translating, use Pyramid's documentation on [working with those files](https://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#creating-a-translation-string). You don't need Babel if you can extract your messages any other way.

As a sidenote: Everything you use for the translation process wraps around Pythons gettext, so if you run into any problems, you might even go down to that library. This will work in any case if you have a valid catalog.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It explains how to do i18n pretty well, but I don't see the connection to Python 3 though, which is really what I'm after. I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question. Please see that for what I was really after.